# Why doesn't grep work in pattern with colon

Tags: regex, linux, bash, grep

I know a colon: should be literal, so I'm not clear why a grep matches all lines. Here's a file called "test":

```
cat test
123|4444
4546|4444
666666|5678
7777777|7890675::1
```

I need to match the line with::1. Of course, the real case is more complicated, so I can't simply search for "::1". I tried many iterations, like

```
grep -E '^[0-9]|[0-9]:' test
grep -E '^[0-9]|[0-9]::1' test
```

But they return all lines:

```
123|4444
4546|4444
666666|5678
7777777|7890675::1
```

I am expecting to match just the last line. Any idea why that is?

This is GNU/Linux bash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues:

1. The regex `[0-9]` matches any *single* digit. Since you have multiple digits, you need to replace those parts with `[0-9]+`, which matches one *or more* digits. If you want to allow an empty sequence with no digits, replace the `+` with a `*`, which means “zero or more”.
2. The pipe character `|` means “alternative”s in regex. What you provided will match *either* a digit at the start of the line, *or* a digit followed by a colon. Since every line has at least one of those, you match every line. To get a literal `|` character, you can use either `[|]` or `\|`; the second option is usually preferred in most styles.

Applying both of these, you get `^[0-9]+\|[0-9]+::1`.

Comment: `\|` may be more popular, but `[|]` is *demonstrably superior*: It can be injected into a wider variety of string types and quoting contexts without requiring modification.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I mentioned both, and phrased it as “usually preferable in most styles”, to try to avoid a style dispute. There are reasons to prefer either: `[|]` works in both ERE and BRE, and doesn’t need to be escaped in as many strings, but causes inconsistencies since `[\]` doesn’t work, and it might be harder to read because it’s less clear you’re escaping something.

Answer (score 4):

The pipe needs to be escaped *and* you need to allow repeated digits:

```
grep -E '^[0-9]+\|[0-9]+:' test
```

Otherwise `^[0-9]` is all that needs to match for a line to be retained by the `grep`.

Comment: @ChuckPedro alas, there are two problems.

Answer (score 2):

Given:

```
$ echo "$txt"
123|4444
4546|4444
666666|5678
7777777|7890675::1
```

Use repetition (`+` means 'one or more') and character classes:

```
$ echo "$txt" | grep -E '^[[:digit:]]+[|][[:digit:]]+[:]+'
7777777|7890675::1
```

Since `|` is a regex meta character, it has to be either escaped (`\|`) or in a character class.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use a tool like awk that can process the *fields* of each line, and match lines where the *2nd field* ends with "::1"

```
awk -F'|' '$2 ~ /::1$/' test
```